# Access local network devices from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

there is an app from pioneer for  controlling my AV receiver. Unfortunately it is no longer working on Android 11 or even 10.
It is called iControlAV5.
Now I have the idea, to check why the app freezes. Therefore I downloaded the app and loaded it to Android Studio.
Unfortunately I only reach the freezing point when the app has found the receiver in my local network...
How do I configure Android Studio so that I will be able to access my local network?
Any ideas?
Regards,
Dodger

Comment: Your PC should do that. Not Android Studio. And then the used emulator.

Comment: The receiver and the PC are connected to the same network. And the emulator that comes with Studio needs to be configured and I don't know how.